# Как отслеживать заполнение полей?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

У меня есть 4 EditText-а, я хочу выполнить определенную функцию если поля заполнены(имеют хотя бы 1 символ)

Comment: Варианта два. В первом случае вы ловите во время ввода текста, во втором проверяете при нажатии на кнопку. В любом случае условие,  и 3 логических И

Comment: Интерфейс есть `editTextView.setOnChangeTextListener` или как то так а внутри 3 метода для отслеживание текста